# How to use window.scroll with horizontal scroll to get element position

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to get element position while scrolling in a horizontal web page. I tried to use

main scrolling:

```
$('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
this.scrollLeft -= (delta*60);
});
```

then:

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    alert('Anything');
  });
```

But that doesn't work at all. I tried using mousewheel plugin

```
$('.internal.th').on('mousewheel',function(event) {
  console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);
});
```

But it keeps displaying the same position `-0 -1 100` no matter how much i scroll

I tried

```
$('.internal.th').on('scroll', function() {
  var val = $(this).scrollLeft()
  if (val >= 100) alert('Hello')
```

})

but it doesn't do anything at all

The idea is getting some item position from the left related to the window to manage another element rotation so I want to keep tracking the main item positing while scrolling horizontally not vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery provides APIs

[offset](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) 
[position](https://api.jquery.com/position/)

you can use those

Below is a sample with both vertical and horizontal scrollbars

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
          console.log(event.target);
          console.log($("#p3").position());
          console.log($("#p3").offset());
          console.log($("#p3").position().top - $("body").scrollTop());
          console.log($("#p3").position().left - $("body").scrollLeft());
 }, true);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>dasdasd</p>
<p>dasdasd</p>
<p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p>
<p style="width: 2500px;display:inline-block">dasdasd<div ></div></p>
<p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p id="p3">dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p><p>dasdasd</p>
```

**Important**: position and offset is relative to parent tag's position and offset

Comment: The problem here is with horizontal scroll itself it doesn't fetch any correct data. $(window).scroll(function() { doesn't work at all

Comment: to detect entire window scroll you cannot use jQuery, I can provide a `setTimeout` solution

Comment: the offset works only on page load not with scrolling horizontally

Comment: document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    console.log(event.target);
}, true);
 displays the html code in the console

Comment: that is only a sample for how detect it, now I put the entire dummy code, I simply made 1 random `<p>` tag 2500px for horizontal scrollbar

Comment: console.log($("#p3").position()); Thanks a lot I really appreciate it.